# Linux group permission not applying correctly with hard link

Tags: linux, permissions, links

I have a log file located at /var/log/snort/alerts. I want to grant one of my users access to read this file, however, I don't want to grant that user access to the directory /var/log/snort.

My solution was to create a group read_snort_alerts, add the user to the group, then make the file owned by that group. Then I was going to make a hard link somewhere that granted the user direct read access to the file.

But I'm still getting permission denied.

Here is the file permissions on the original file /var/log/snort/alerts. Anyone in the owning group has read access.

```
$ ls -l | grep alert
-rw-r----- 2 snort read_snort_alerts  6067 Oct 9 20:40 alert
```

Here is the hard link

```
$ ls -l | grep /tmp/hardlink
-rw-r----- 2 snort read_snort_alerts  6067 Oct 9 20:40 hardlink
```

The user is named john, and belongs to the correct group.

```
$ groups john
john : john sudo read_snort_alerts
```

Then as John I cannot read the file.

```
$ less /tmp/hardlink
hardlink: Permission denied
```

Here are the permissions on the directory of the folder that contains the original file.

```
$ ls -ld /var/log/snort
drwx-s--- 2 snort adm 4096 Oct 9 21:19 /var/log/snort
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167006/linux-permission-group

I needed to log out and log back in again in order for the new group to take effect.